# Why does only the value of p2 change here?

Tags: c++, pointers

So I am new to the concept of pointers and I had a question regarding the following sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int value1 = 5, value2 =15;
   int * p1, * p2;

   p1 = &value1;
   p2 = &value2;
   *p1 = 10;
   *p2 = *p1;

   cout << "value1 is " << value1 << "\n"; 
   cout << "value2 is " << value2 << "\n";

   p1 = p2;
   *p1 = 20;

   cout << "value1 is " << value1 << "\n"; 
   cout << "value2 is " << value2 << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value1 is 10
value2 is 10
value1 is 10
value2 is 20
```

I don't understand why value1 and value2 don't both have 20 as their new value.

```
   p1 = &value1;
   p2 = &value2;
   *p1 = 10;
   *p2 = *p1;
```

Here it makes sense. I believe that we have assigned p1 and p2 to the address of value1 and value2
then we assigned p1 a value that can access the address of value1 making value1 = 10 and since we set p2 = p1 the same will happen for value2. Thus both values will be equal to 10. Then in the lines

```
p1 = p2;
*p1 = 20;
```

We set p1 = p2; then give *p1 a value of 20 but in the terminal only outputs the value of value2 as 20 which should be assigned to p2. Why does value1 not equal 20 after this, why is only value2 equal to 20?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you only assign `20` to `value2`:

```
p1 = p2;  // from here both p1 and p2 will be pointing at value2
*p1 = 20; // value2 is assigned 20
```

Some addresses in memory where the `value` variables are stored.

```
  addr0    addr1 
+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 |
+--------+--------+
```

Now to what you are doing:

```
p1 = &value1; // p1 = addr0
p2 = &value2; // p2 = addr1

*p1 = 10;     // dereference p1 and assign 10 (value1 = 10)
*p2 = *p1;    // dereference p2 and assign the value from the dereferenced p1
              // (value2 = value1)

p1 = p2;      // assign p1 the address p2 is pointing at (p1 = addr1)
*p1 = 20;     // dereference p1 and assign 20 (value2 = 20)
```

Comment: Yes, `p1 = p2` makes `p1` point at the same variable as `p2` is pointing at. `*p1 = *p2` would work if you didn't change what `p1` was pointing at, yes.

Answer (score 2):

After this assignment

```
   p1 = p2;
```

the pointer p1 now points to the variable value2 pointed to by the pointer p2. That is the both pointers now point to the same variable.

So this statement

```
 *p1 = 20;
```

is changing the pointed variable value2.

As for these statements

```
   p1 = &value1;
   p2 = &value2;
   *p1 = 10;
   *p2 = *p1;
```

then in the last statement

```
   *p2 = *p1;
```

the variable value2 pointed to by the pointer p2 is assigned with the value of the variable value1 pointed to by the pointer p1. The pointers themselves were not changed.